# Logging does not write anything in my file

Tags: python, logging, format

I have problems with **logging** in Python 3.7 I use Spyder as editor
This code is working normally and creates a file and writes in it.

```
import logging
LOG_FORMAT="%(Levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="C:\\Users\\MOHAMED\\Desktop\\Learn python\\tst.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.info("Our first message.")
```

The problem is when I add the format in my file this code does not write anything in tst file.

```
import logging
LOG_FORMAT="%(Levelname)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s"
logging.basicConfig(filename="C:\\Users\\MOHAMED\\Desktop\\Learn python\\tst.log",
                    level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format=LOG_FORMAT)
logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.info("Our first message.")
```

Comment: Try using lowercase `levelname` in your LOG_FORMAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are specifying logging variable `Levelname` but you do not use the extra to populate the variable.

try it with

```
logger.info("Our first message.", extra={"Levelname":"test"})
```

also, recommend the docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html